# rspec - how to change these simple "x.should == 'val' lines

Tags: ruby, rspec

For rspec change to use expect().to instead of .should, how would I change the folowing:

```
  ...
  describe '#push_state' do
    def process(klass)
      state = OpenStruct.new(:namespace => "ROOT", :scope => :instance, :owner => "ROOT")
      klass.new(state, nil).process
    end 

    it "should push and return all old state info after block" do
      class PushStateHandler1 < Handlers::Base
        def process
          push_state(:namespace => "FOO", :scope => :class, :owner => "BAR") do
            namespace.should == "FOO"
            scope.should == :class
            owner.should == "BAR"
          end 
          namespace.should == "ROOT"
          owner.should == "ROOT"
          scope.should == :instance
        end 
      end 
  ...
```

Every variety I have fails, usuaully with `undefined method expect for #<PushStateHandler1:0x000000010a3470>`

For example I've tried:

```
expect(namespace).to eq "FOO"
expect{(namespace) eq "FOO"}.to be_true
```

Comment: Why do you need this class definition on the "it" block ?

Comment: does the method(#push_state) return a object?

Comment: on a more simple spec it works like expected: https://gist.github.com/guilherme/60a10a393320c8a4443e

What i think is really strange in your code is the push_state method that receive a block that probably current runs on the context PushStateHandler1 (e.g. theres a yield inside the method definition) and not on the context of the rspec.

Answer (score 0):

The `expect` method is defined in the scope of the `it` block. In this case, you've defined a class within that block, an instance method within that class and a block within that instance method. I don't know the specify Ruby scoping rules, but it's not surprising that the variables in that inner block are not interpreted in the scope of the outer block. The `should` method only worked because it's defined on `Object`.

So, to answer your questions, I don't know off hand how to translate from `should` to `expect` except to say that you somehow have to pass along and use the binding from the outer block to evaluate whatever `expect` expressions you're trying to use.